# How to keep track "which Third Party android applications are accessing Network(ConnectityManager)"?

Tags: android, networking

I am new to android,i want to develop application that should monitor which other installed android applications are accessing to INTERNET or Using Network interface at given point of time.
For Example:

WhatsApp is uploading photo to this IP address "0.0.0.0" 1 minute ago.

So is there any API's present in android to keep track these informations or what are the other possible techniques to achieve this goal.